# SCSS/Sass Compass: How to locate duplicate selectors

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I just inherited a nice little project where the CSS was split in multiple small CSS files because of IFrames.

So now that I'm linking everything together and putting it in SCSS, I find myself with tons duplicate selectors with exactly the same styling in them.

I'm guessing there is a nice little option in compass SCSS to have it "suggest" duplication of tags

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Jason

Comment: Not related to Sass&Compass, but you might try this if you have Firefox handy. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem a while back and the end result was a quick Sasslint tool I wrote to parse .sass files and output the line numbers of each duplicate selector: https://github.com/dfltr/Sasslint

I haven't updated it to explicitly support SCSS, nor do I know if any modifications are even needed to do so, but it might be a good starting point for you.